# Kafka Streams use manually created internal topics giving TopicAuthorizationException

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use KStreams to consume data from a topic, do some logic on the data and write to KTable. Due to security reasons, the application cannot be given the permission to create the internal topics.
Based on the documentation from [here](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/security#:%7E:text=To%20avoid%20providing%20this%20permission%20to%20your%20application%2C%20you%20can%20create%20the%20required%20internal%20topics%20manually.) I understand we can create the topics manually and the application will use those manually created topics.

I created the internal topics manually, made sure the partition count, replication factor is same as the input topic. I created ACL (operation all) for the application-id set in the application.
However when I run the application i get the exception:

```
stream-thread [main] Unexpected error during topic description for test-KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000004-changelog.
Error message was: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Topic authorization failed.
 [Consumer clientId=test-3ed0ce81-765e-45da-bf30-345c83c35e6d-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=test1] Rebalance failed.

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Could not create topic test-KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000004-changelog.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopicManager.getNumPartitions(InternalTopicManager.java) ~[kafka-streams-2.8.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopicManager.validateTopics(InternalTopicManager.java) ~[kafka-streams-2.8.1.jar!/:na]
```

I saw [this](https://dev.to/ananddas/kafka-streams-disable-internal-topic-creation-454m#:%7E:text=Register%20the%20internal%20topics%20with%20the%20Streams%20instance) article on registering the internal topic with stream. However, I was not able to figure out the code to add the topic configuration to the stream.
I looked in to [StreamConfig.Topic_Prefix](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/manage-topics#:%7E:text=any%20configs%20from-,TopicConfig,-to%20your%20StreamsConfig) configurations but didn't find the option to set the internal topic name.

Can some one help in understanding what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you are referring to, the distinction between [user topics](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/manage-topics#streams-developer-guide-topics-user) vs. [internal topics](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/manage-topics#streams-developer-guide-topics-internal) is clear: User topics must be created manually, while internal topics are managed by Kafka Streams itself. Your issue deals with internal topics.

The documentation states that if security is enabled on Kafka brokers, admin permissions must be granted, so the application can create internal topics. Make sure that your ACLs grant these permissions specifically for the internal topics. That might be where your issue of "`not authorized to access topics: [application id]`" could arise.
See "[Required ACL setting for secure Kafka clusters](https://kafka.apache.org/34/documentation/streams/developer-guide/security.html#id1)".

The guide also mentions that default broker configurations are applied to internal topics. If needed, you can override these default configurations by adding configurations from [`TopicConfig`](https://kafka.apache.org/34/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/config/TopicConfig.html) to your [`StreamsConfig`](https://kafka.apache.org/34/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.html) with the appropriate prefix. That may be relevant if you have specific requirements for the internal topics, such as segment time or retention periods.

---

The [OP perplexeddev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3985332/perplexeddev) adds in [the comments )(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76949239/kafka-streams-use-manually-created-internal-topics-giving-topicauthorizationexce/76997846#comment135750117_76997846):

> I thought it had to do with ACLs and I had read the ACL setting document that you have sent earlier, but I somehow missed the last sentence on prefixed resource pattern `--resource-pattern-type prefixed --topic your.application.id --operation All`.
> I added that and now it works.

The last sentence was:

> Since all internal topics as well as the embedded consumer group name are prefixed with the application id, it is recommended to use ACLs on prefixed resource pattern to configure control lists to allow client to manage all topics and consumer groups started with this prefix as `--resource-pattern-type prefixed --topic your.application.id --operation All` (see [KIP-277](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-277+-+Fine+Grained+ACL+for+CreateTopics+API) and [KIP-290](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-290%3A+Support+for+Prefixed+ACLs) for details).

Comment: I thought it had to do with ACLs and i had read the ACL setting document that you have sent earlier but i somehow missed the last sentence on prefixed resource pattern --resource-pattern-type prefixed --topic your.application.id --operation All. I added that and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: @perplexedDev Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually need to override the internal topic name to a pre-created topic (if you're unable to get admin permissions for your application to create topics) it is possible just in case anyone else gets stuck.

You simply need to set the store when performing the operation.  For example if I want to perform a reduce operation in kafka streams which will need an internal changelog topic, you can set the topic name it will use with:

```
stream.reduce(eventReducer, Materialized.as("myStore"))
```

The autogenerated topics for this operation would be `<ApplicationId>-<OperatorName>-<Suffix>` or based on your error log `test-KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000004-changelog`
When you set the store when performing an operation it replaces the OperatorName with the store name that you set so the resulting topic would be `test-myStore-changelog`.  This allows you to pre-create your internal topics that a kafka streams application needs if you're unable to give it admin permissions to be able to do it on its own.