# Unit test KafkaStreams gives IllegalArgumentException: Unknown topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, junit, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

I have a app that uses KStream to read from Kafka, filter the data based on the header, and write to KTable.

```
public Topology buildTopology() {
        KStream<String,String> inputStream = builder.stream("topicname");
        KStream<String,String> filteredStream = inputStream.transformValues(KSExtension::new)
                .filter((key,value) -> value!=null);
        
        kTable = filteredStream.groupByKey()
                .reduce(((value1, value2) -> value2), Materialized.as("ktable"));
        
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);
        streams.start();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
        return builder.build();
    }
```

I'm trying to create a unit test for this using TopologyTestDriver

```
private TopologyTestDriver td;
    private TestInputTopic<String, String> inputTopic;
    private TestOutputTopic<String, String> outputTopic;
    private Topology topology;
    private Properties streamConfig;

@BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        streamConfig = new Properties();
        streamConfig.setProperty(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "AppId");
        streamConfig.setProperty(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "foo:1234");
        streamConfig.setProperty(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        streamConfig.setProperty(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());

        topology = new Topology();
        td = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, streamConfig);
        inputTopic = td.createInputTopic("input-topic", Serdes.String().serializer(), Serdes.String().serializer());
        outputTopic = td.createOutputTopic("output-topic", Serdes.String().deserializer(), Serdes.String().deserializer());
    }
 @Test
    void buildTopology(){
        inputTopic.pipeInput("key1", "value1");
        topology = app.buildTopology();
    }
```

When I run the test, i get the exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown topic: input-topic"

```
DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder - No source topics using pattern subscription found, initializing consumer's subscription collection.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown topic: input-topic
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.pipeRecord(TopologyTestDriver.java:582)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.pipeRecord(TopologyTestDriver.java:945)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TestInputTopic.pipeInput(TestInputTopic.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TestInputTopic.pipeInput(TestInputTopic.java:137)
    at testclassname.buildTopology()
```

Can some one help me understand what I am missing here?

Comment: Would you mind including a stack trace? I'm surmising that it's happening on the `createInputTopic()` call, but it would be nice to know.

Comment: @entpnerd I have added the stack trace in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you are creating an *empty* [`Topology`](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/streams/Topology.html), used to initialize the [`TopologyTestDriver`](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/streams/Topology.html):

```java
topology = new Topology();
td = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, streamConfig);
```

When this empty topology is used to instantiate the `TopologyTestDriver` with `td = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, streamConfig);`, the test driver does not know about any topics, since no topology was effectively built.

I suppose this is why, when you try to pipe input into `"input-topic"` using `inputTopic.pipeInput("key1", "value1");`, the test driver throws an `IllegalArgumentException` complaining about an "`Unknown topic: input-topic`".

---

You should call your `buildTopology()` method to generate the actual topology you are testing, and use that when creating your `TopologyTestDriver`.

Make sure that the topic names in your test (`input-topic`, `output-topic`) match those in your actual application (`"topicname"`).

```java
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    streamConfig = new Properties();
    streamConfig.setProperty(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "AppId");
    streamConfig.setProperty(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "foo:1234");
    streamConfig.setProperty(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    streamConfig.setProperty(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());

    // Create the topology using your actual code
    topology = app.buildTopology();

    // Now create a TopologyTestDriver using the real topology
    td = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, streamConfig);

    // The topic name here should match the actual topic you use in the real topology
    inputTopic = td.createInputTopic("topicname", Serdes.String().serializer(), Serdes.String().serializer());

    // Create output topic if you need it
    // outputTopic = td.createOutputTopic("output-topic", Serdes.String().deserializer(), Serdes.String().deserializer());
}

@Test
void buildTopology(){
    inputTopic.pipeInput("key1", "value1");
    // Your assertions here
}
```

Note: I removed the output topic from the setup because in your code snippet you did not specify the output topic where your `KTable` gets written to. You may add it back if your actual application writes to an output topic.

---

> I have updated the code where I add the name of the ktable store.
> How do I test the value was added to the ktable?

You can query the state store that backs the `KTable` to check its contents.
In Kafka Streams, each KTable is backed by a [state store](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/architecture.html#streams_architecture_state) (even a [versioned one very recently, Aug. 2023](https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-versioned-state-store-in-kafka-streams/)), and you can directly interact with this store in tests.

Make sure that you set a store name for your KTable in your topology:

```java
kTable = filteredStream.groupByKey()
        .reduce(((value1, value2) -> value2), Materialized.as("myKTableStore"));
```

Here, `"myKTableStore"` is the name of the state store that backs the KTable.

In your test, you can retrieve the store from the `TopologyTestDriver` and check the value for a specific key:

```java
@Test
void buildTopology() {
    inputTopic.pipeInput("key1", "value1");

    // Retrieve the state store
    ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, String> keyValueStore = 
        td.getKeyValueStore("myKTableStore");

    // Assert that the KTable contains the expected value for the key
    assertEquals("value1", keyValueStore.get("key1"));
}
```

That way, you can validate that your `KTable` contains the expected key-value pairs.

Note that [`ReadOnlyKeyValueStore`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.5/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/ReadOnlyKeyValueStore.java) is a part of the Kafka Streams API. Import it as needed.
You can see it used in "[Kafka Streams Interactive Queries / Querying local key-value stores](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-local-key-value-stores)"

[image: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/_images/streams-interactive-queries-api-01.png]

---

> How can I input headers to the input topic in the test? I couldn't find an option. I filter on the header values here `inputStream.transformValues(KSExtension::new)`

In Kafka Streams' [`TopologyTestDriver`](https://kafka.apache.org/34/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/TopologyTestDriver.html), the ability to directly add headers to the [`TestInputTopic`](https://kafka.apache.org/34/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/TestInputTopic.html) is somewhat limited.
However, you can use the lower-level `pipeInput()` method that allows you to pass a [`ConsumerRecord` object](https://kafka.apache.org/34/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html), which can have headers.

You will need to build the `ConsumerRecord` manually and then use it:

```java
@Test
void buildTopology() {
    // Create a Headers object and add your custom headers
    Headers headers = new RecordHeaders();
    headers.add(new RecordHeader("myHeaderKey", "myHeaderValue".getBytes()));

    // Create a ConsumerRecord with headers
    ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record = new ConsumerRecord<>(
            "topicname", // topic
            0, // partition
            0, // offset
            "key1".getBytes(), // key
            "value1".getBytes(), // value
            headers // headers
    );

    // Pipe the record into TopologyTestDriver
    td.pipeInput(record);

    // The rest of your test
}
```

Make sure to replace `"topicname"` with the name of the topic you are actually reading from in your topology, and adjust the key, value, and headers as needed for your test.

That should allow you to include headers in your test records, which should then be processed by your `transformValues` operation as expected.

Comment: I had a follow up question, I have updated the code where I add the name of the ktable store. How do I test the value was added to the ktable?

Comment: great, thank you for the detailed explanation. I am new to Kafka Stream and TopologyTestDriver so this is really helpful. One last query, how can I input headers to the input topic in the test? I couldn't find an option. I filter on the header values here inputStream.transformValues(KSExtension::new)

Comment: I have another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76949239/kafka-streams-use-manually-created-internal-topics-giving-topicauthorizationexce
You seem to be very experienced in Kafka Streams, do you have any thoughts on this question?